# I get this error time data '27:07.5' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to find the difference between the StartTime and LastTime (minutes) in this DataFrame:

```
StartTime     LastTime  
  1  00:02:05    00:02:05
  2  00:07:05    00:07:05
  3  00:12:06    00:12:06
  4  00:17:06   00:17:06
```

When I run the following code on the data

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%H:%M.%S"

# You could also pass datetime.time object in this part and convert it to string.
time_start = str(UDP_interval['StartTime']) 
time_end = str(UDP_interval['LastTime'])

# Then get the difference here.    
diff = datetime.strptime(time_end, date_format) - 
datetime.strptime(time_start, date_format)

# Get the time in hours i.e. 9.60, 8.5
result = diff.seconds / 3600;
```

I get this error:

`dtype: object' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: `%H` is 24 hour clock so a value of 27 is invalid

Comment: The example times you supplied are separated by colons, but the code uses a full stop instead of the second colon

Comment: Is there a typo for date_format? Should it be date_format = "%H:%M:%S"?

Comment: As others have commented, you simply have a typo in your format string.

Comment: I have corrected this now the date_format = "%H:%M:%S" however I still get the error dtype: object' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just use:

```
t_start = list(map(int, str(UDP_interval['StartTime']).split(':'))) # get hours, minutes, seconds separately
t_end = list(map(int, str(UDP_interval['LastTime']).split(':')))
diff = (t_start[0] - t_end[0]) + (t_start[1] - t_start[1]) / 60 + (t_start[2] - t_start[2]) / 3600
```

Comment: I have corrected this now the date_format = "%H:%M:%S" however I still get the error dtype: object' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: Thank you for your solution with this solution i get another error TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. You need to replace map(...) with list(map(...))